# Solve the differential equations problem below using power series. 2y''-6x•y'=7

Tags: power-series

Solve the differential equation below, using power series$$
2y'' - 6x*y' = 7
$$Hi sorry to bother you guys but I'm having trouble answering because I'm not good at solving this equation,

Comment: Welcome to the forum! Have you tried to solve this yourself? I'm asking because if the answer is yes, then it could be that you're just a small step away from finishing the solution. So please show your own work.

Comment: Replace $y$ by $a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+....$ (or better $\Sigma_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n$) in the two places where it occurs, then identify coefficients of the same $x^n$ in LHS and RHS. This will give you a recurrence relationship.

Comment: Thank you but can you please elaborate more cause I'm very slow at learning

Comment: $2(a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+....)''-6x(a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+....)'=7 \iff 2(2a_2+6a_3x+...)-6x(a_1+2_2x+....)=7 \iff 4a_2=7, 12a_3-6a_1=0, $ etc. giving you $a_2=7/4, a_3=\frac12 a_1...$, etc.

Comment: thank you! how about this one? Determine the power series expansion with at least three non-zero terms for 
[3cos(x)+5(e^x)^2].